# How to use CSV Dataset Config's variable in Bean Shell Post Processor in Jmeter

Tags: testing, jmeter, automated-tests, performance-testing, load-testing

In my application I have two scenarios.

- **1. Create:** Here we book a hotel room. After booking application returns a transaction ID.
- **2. Cancel:** We need to pass the transaction Id to the application to cancel booking.
- I want to test with jmeter in such a way that after a create call is made, the cancel call of the respective create is called with the generated transaction ID automatically.

So I have created two thread groups. One for create where I am calling create API, saving the transaction Id in a CSV file using Regular Expression Extractor & Bean Shell Post Processor. Another thread is for cancel where I am picking the transaction ID using CSV Dataset Config & calling the cancel API.

Problem is I want to delete that transaction ID from CSV file after calling the cancel API. I think Bean Shell Post Processor will do the job. This is my CSV Data Set Config:

[image]

Here is my Bean Shell Post Processor code:

```
File inputFile = new File("/home/demo/LocalFolder/CSV/result.csv");
File tempFile = new File("/home/demo/LocalFolder/CSV/myTempFile.csv");

BufferedReader reader;
try {
    reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));

    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

    String lineToRemove = vars.get("transactionId");
    //String lineToRemove = "${transactionId}";
    String currentLine;

    while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        // trim newline when comparing with lineToRemove
        String trimmedLine = currentLine.trim();
        if(trimmedLine.equals(lineToRemove)) continue;
        writer.write(currentLine + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    }
    writer.close(); 
    reader.close(); 
    boolean successful = tempFile.renameTo(inputFile);
    System.out.println("Completed");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

But the transaction ID is not getting deleted from the file. I think that `vars.get("transactionId")` is not returning anything or returning wrong value. If I hardcode a transation ID then the code works fine. Can anyone help me?

Comment: The approach of manipulating a file during load test is not a scalable one. Is there a specific reason why you want to write them into a file? Passing the extracted value to the next thread "in memory" just works fine. Can you please elaborate why you need to write this to a file and then delete it?

Comment: Since you want cancel call sequentially AFTER create call, I think using 2 thread groups complicates your scenario unneededly. Just have them in one group, and save a transaction ID as variable. 

But if you really want to use 2 thread groups, @Kranthi Paidi is right: this is not a scalable solution (since many threads will be waiting in queue to read/write the same file). Use "Inter-Thread Communication" plug-in, which works as a FIFO queue (which is essentially what you are trying to achieve in your script).

Answer (score 0):

JMeter Variables are **local** to the current Thread Group only, in order to pass the data between Thread Groups you need to use JMeter Properties (`props` instead of `vars`). See [Knit One Pearl Two: How to Use Variables in Different Thread Groups](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/knit-one-pearl-two-how-use-variables-different-thread-groups) article for more detailed explanation and usage example.

P.S. Maybe it would be easier to use [HTTP Simple Table Server](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HttpSimpleTableServer/) instead?